# IONIC - Get value from $http json

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I've spent over 3 hours trying to get a value out of object that is returned by $http.get() but to no avail.

Here's the json output that i'm trying to process

> {"ValidateUserResult":true}

```
$scope.doLogin = function () {
    $http.get('test.svc/ValidateUser/json/username/password').then(function(result) {
        alert("hello" + result.ValidateUserRequest);
        return result;
    }, function (err) {
        alert("WHAT");
    })
```

Any and all help is appreciated!! ): THANKS!!!

Comment: You are trying to fetch data straight from the response object (the result parameter), try to use result.data.ValidateUserResult.

Next time, you should include the code here and NOT include it as an image....

Comment: Seriously? You include code and its result which you discuss as IMAGE? Please edit your question and paste the code and its output here.

Comment: @HaukurKristinsson the .data was the thing that I've been missing all along! Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @planetmaker Noted and updated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @HaukurKristinsson mentioned, I was missing the .data.

```
 alert("hello" + result.data.ValidateUserRequest);
```

Thanks!